# "Cross Org Data Proxy User" has attached itself to my App

Tags: profile, app, defaults

I cannot delete my Custom App because a System Profile has it selected as the Default App.

As part of [Cross-Organization data sharing](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cod_overview.htm) there is a new `Cross Org Data Proxy User` that appears amongst my list of profiles, and also when editing my Custom App:

[image: app-profiles]

Unfortunately my app has somehow become the **compulsory default** for this profile. At first it looked like I could drill into the profile and change the default, but any attempt to edit the profile gives an error:

[image: profile-edit]

[image: validation-error]

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
>
> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Standard tabsets are not permitted for this profile".

Do any gurus know how to edit that profile or deselect my app from the default choice?

**Edit:**

Today I tried some URL hacking (much like this technique for undeletable record types) to no avail:

[image: no-default-app]

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   You must choose a default App

Comment: Definitely raise this with support.

Comment: @bigassforce did you ever get a response for this issue. I'm having the same problem right now

Comment: hey @Orlando, they fixed it by uninstalling the package in that particular case. I've been lucky enough not to encounter it since.

Comment: The exact same issue is happening in one of my orgs right now. "Cross org data proxy user" has made my custom App default, and there is no way to change that, which keeps me from un-installing the app. Very frustrating.

Comment: Try creating another-nother custom app, and during the wizard select as "default" the problem profiles. This will "free up" the actual app you care about, then you can delete it again. I think. It was something tricky like that.

Comment: Yes @bigassforce, I had just tried it and came back here to post when I found your answer. Created a "Dummy App", make it default for "Cross Org...". Interesting, when I tried to the delete the app I wanted, it had been made default for System Admin. But I was able to change default App for System Admin without any problem. THEN, I was finally able to delete the app I needed. Annoying work-around, but beats having to contact Support for dev orgs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the Custom App from the Profile.

There is no way to change the Profile Defaults from the App.

**However, this works:**

1. Go to Setup > Create > Apps > New (yes, make another one)
2. Enter some temporary `App Label` and `App Name`
3. Click through the Image and Tabs parts of the wizard
4. Choose both `Visible` and `Default` for "Cross Org Data Proxy User"
   [image]

This will break / steal the defaultness from that problematic profile. Now you can manipulate or delete the original app (which was not possible when it was locked as the default)

At this point you may be able to try editing "Cross Org Data Proxy User" and try setting the Default App to "App Launcher" or something native. Then delete the temporary app from 2.